# DATABASE design for storing specifications?

Tags: database-design

I am creating , a site like gsmarena , can any one help me with database design to store mobile specifications like here "http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_padfone_infinity_lite-6120.php"
as user can add more custom specification ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have Phone table where you store phone.
Create two another attributes and sub-attribute tables.

Attribute Table will look like below:

- AttributeId (PK, auto generated int is recommended)
- PhoneId (FK to Phone tablet, not null)
- AttributeKey (String, not null - text like "DISPLAY" "DATA" etc.)
- AttributeValue (string, null)

SubAttribute Table will look like below:

- SubAttributeId (PK, auto generated int is recommended)
- AttributeId (FK to Attribute tablet, not null)
- SubAttributeKey (String, not null - text like "Dimensions" "Size" etc.)
- SubAttributeValue (string, null)

Comment: And one more question ,which will be good for phoneid ? serialized   or normal data?

Comment: generally you should prefer auto-generated integer IDs. In a separate table, map that integer ID to phone name etc.